# Wit.ai doesn't understand entities but on_off instead?

Tags: wit.ai

I have defined an entity "team" with value "FC Barcelona" and the alias "Barcelona". The language of the app is set to German. Any idea why "Barcelona" is recognized as a wit/on_off entity? Actually for every sentence (doesn't matter what) I enter, the wit/on_off entity is recognized with some random word as the value.

[image: Wit.ai Understanding]

A strange thing is also that I have the wit/on_off entity twice there.

[image: Wit.ai on_off]

That's an app that I imported from the export of another app. Can I delete one on_off? But which one?

Answer (score 1):

You can simple delete the mistakenly recognized on_off entity and add your team entity. After some samples it wit.ai should improve the recognition.